# Will I get a postback each month when using subscriptions?

Tags: android-pay

I am using Google Wallet For Digital Goods.

Will I get a callback each month when money gets transferred or will the postback URL only get called once when setting up the subscription?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid at this very moment Google Wallet only notifies the user when the subscription is cancelled.

I asked the same myself on google wallet for digital goods forum :

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/in-app-payments/YFaCBDwaF9g

See the 2nd answer from Mihai Ionescu from Google

EDIT: As suggested by Qix below, I'm quoting the answer given by Google below:

> 1. After the subscription is setup, you will receive a postback only when the subscription is cancelled:
>      https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/subscriptions#6
> 2. Currently the merchant can cancel or refund a subscription from the Merchant Center. We are working on adding API support for
>      cancellations and refunds.

Please note that the forum entry is from late 2012, however as of May 2014 things doesn't seem to have changed much, as Google still postbacks only for Subscription Cancellations

Comment: Could you post the second answer here as a quote?